# Qual o funcionamento por trás das variáveis de ambiente?

Tags: sistema-operacional, dotnet-cli, variáveis-de-ambiente

Olá, sou novato em programação, eu baixei o SDK do .NET 5 para aprender sobre, mas me deparei com a linha de comandos dele em Português, eu realmente não sei o que define o idioma, mas pesquisei e descobri que talvez se eu executasse o comando `set DOTNET_CLI_UI_LANGUAGE=en` eu conseguiria mudar para inglês. Até então só o que eu fazia era criar variáveis de ambiente na interface gráfica do Windows (eu só sabia que elas podiam executar arquivos binários do meu PC), eu não entendi como esse comando poderia criar uma nova variável de ambiente se eu não tinha nem informado o diretório, como faço na GUI.

Eu queria por favor saber um pouco sobre como funciona esse conceito de variáveis de ambiente, se alguém simpatizar com a minha ignorância poderia clarear um pouco minha mente? Agradeço desde já qualquer conhecimento compartilhado.

Comment: Você quer saber o conceito e a importância das variáveis de ambiente ou o funcionamento específico em .Net?

Comment: o conceito delas, não especificamente em .net